# Rspec Test : How do we check for an input field in a bootstrap modal? And how do we fill in that field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have these two input fields in my modal:

```
Amount: <%= f.text_field :prin, :onKeyPress=>"return isNumberKey(event)"  , :required => 'true'%>
Rate: <%= f.number_field :interest_rate, :min => "12", :max => "30", :required =>'true'  %>
```

Typical `fill_in` doesn't work for this in spec test.

Comment: Are they visible during fill_in?

Comment: It is really hard to tell anything without seeing your test with `typical fill_in`.

Comment: Is my answer worked?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `within` to identify the modal's `class name` and use `fill_in` like below

```
within(".your_modal_class_name") do 
  fill_in 'prin', with: 'some_value'
  fill_in 'interest_rate', with: 'some_value'
end
```